# How to ssh-add to a remote server using a passphrase

Tags: git, ssh-agent

I need to execute a git command on a remote server and I have a private key with a passphrase. How can I `ssh-add` my key to the server so I can run git commands there without copying the private key there? I've searched a lot for this, but did not find pages which would answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the **public key** *content* on the server in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (the file can hold many keys from different people). Then, you can use ssh-add providing your private key so that it can be used when going with ssh against the server.... or you could use -i when using ssh to provide the private key file.

Comment: The solution was to run ssh -A. That way I was able to clone on the remote server.